# Weird segfault after open file?

Tags: c

I'm getting a seg fault when I try and print fname. Can someone explain why this is happening to me? Is it that I'm not allowed to write to a file, close it, and then read from a file? argv[2] is defined. I've tried with multiple different allocations.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //Other stuff

    char *rfile=calloc(1, 2049);
    strcpy(rfile, argv[2]);
    FILE *wfile;
    wfile = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    SaveIndexToFile(index, wfile, alpha);  // This does a whole bunch of writing to a the file.
    fclose(wfile);

    //alpha is declared here, and works just fine.
    RemakeIndex(rfile, alpha);
    return 1;
}
int RemakeIndex(char *fname, WordList * alpha){
    printf("%s", fname);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: rfile is a char*, not a file. That's confusing.

Comment: I would guess that `SaveIndexToFile` corrupts memory somehow.

Comment: I double checked to make sure there were no memory leaks. How would I check to see if memory had been corrupted?

Comment: What do you get when you put the call to `RemakeIndex()` just after the call to `strcpy()`?

Comment: Do not signifcantly change your question after answers had been given, this might make the answers ununderstandble. Rolling back your last edit now. Add "changes" as "updates", as additions to your question.

Comment: "*it still segfault*" no addtional output? Please also see my updated answer on the usage of `printf()`.

Comment: @alk, yeah it still segfaults with no addtional output, even when I fflush(stdout);

Comment: So the issue might lie in what your question's code snippet referrs to as "*other stuff*". We cannot help you with this.

Comment: Someone earlier mentioned corrupted memory. Is there a way I could check for this? Also, if everything up to this point has been freed with no memory leaks, would the output really affect the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not checking the return value of fopen. If the fopen fails it can
return `NULL`. If you are doing something with `NULL` that can undefined behavior. Place this line after opening the file.

```
if ( wfile == NULL ){
    perror("fopen");
    return;
}
```

And check whether the `argc` count is three. If you are not giving arguments to the `./a.out` then accessing the `argv[2]`  can also lead to segmentation fault.

Comment: While I realize this is good coding practice and I will definitely not add this to my code, it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: What are you giving to the `./a.out` in terminal.

Comment: I'm giving it a `./a.out folder/ file.dat` That's the run command, if that's what you're asking. If not I don't understand your question.

Comment: Yeah, it's when I dereference 'fname' in the print statement. It's weird, because it doesn't happen when I dereference rfile in the main.

Comment: Are you having the prototype for that function?

Comment: `s/will/can/g`. Dereferncing a `NULL` pointer is simply undefined behavior, it may not always segfault.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it that I'm not allowed to write to a file, close it, and then read from a file?

Yes, you are not allowed to read from a file [stream] after it had been closed.

---

Note on the (OP's) wording:

- `char * rfile` is called a "pointer to `char`".
- `FILE *` is called a "file-pointer" (or also just "pointer to `FILE`) or commonly (but formally wrong) just "file".

---

Also `RemakeIndex()` is called in `main()` **without** proper protoyping.

To fix this

- either add a prototype before `main()`:

  ```
  int RemakeIndex(char *, WordList *);
  ```
- or move the whole implementation of `RemakeIndex()` before `main()`.

---

Also the `printf()` calls' output might not show up immediately on the console, as `stdout` is line buffered.

To fix this

- either print out a trailing new-line:

  ```
  printf("%s\n", fname);
  ```
- or printf to `stderr`, which itself isn't line bufferd by default:

  ```
  fprintf(strerr, "%s\n", fname);
  ```
- or flush `stdout` after having printed to it:

  ```
  printf("%s\n", fname);
  fflush(stdout);
  ```

Comment: sorry, I meant, am I allowed to open and close, and then open and close the same file? in the same program.

Comment: Yeah, it's declared in my main.h file. Also, I just fixed the code to make it more clear what each variable is.

Comment: @DerekHalden: Regarding your "fix" please see my comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Prototyping the function is very important, the GCC compiler will assume an implicitly declared function (RemakeIndex in your code) has two arguments which are both int, which would make your code look like this:

```
 int RemakeIndex(int fname, int alpha) {
    printf("%s", (char *)fname);
    return 1;
 }
```

On a 64 bit machine and with GCC where pointers are 64 bits and ints are 32 bits then your arguments will be truncated to 32 bits which is likely to cause a segfault. The other answers have mentioned prototyping the function and if you are using a 64bit compiler I would suggest that this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being that I was allocating way too much memory on the heap. I had a loop that was allocating strings of max_length of an unsigned int. Thank you for all of your comments and help!